# UICollectionView, UICollectionViewFlowLayout: different cells width and same defined spacing between cells

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have overloaded the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` to have a single horizontal row slider containing `UIImages` in each `UICollectionViewCell`.

In the overloaded `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, I have set the `minimumLineSpacing` to 0 to get no spacing between `UICollectionViewCells`. (default is 10px)

- In case each cell has the same width, the 0px spacing is correctly displayed
- In case a cell has a bigger width, the 0px are no more taken into account and the default 10px between cells is applied..

I have tried to implement the following method but same result...

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
           layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout 
           minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}
```

- Is it a bug ?
- What is the "trick" to get my 0px spacing between my `UICollectionViewCells` with different width ?

Answer (score 5):

1. Is it a bug? **No**
   This is not a bug, it is the default behavior of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Flow layout is a line breaking layout that means assume that it will place all your cells along a straight line and going to arrange it on the screen. Once it fill a row(no space for a new item), it will break the line and go for the next. `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` assures **minimumLineSpacing** no the exact. If your item sizes are different flow layout arranges the cells in such a way that to keep the minimum line spacing. So line size may increase but never be a lower value than you set previously.

   [image]
2. I dont think it is possible with flow layout, you should use one custom layout. Check [this](https://github.com/jayslu/JSPintDemo) iam not sure that you can set the spacing to zero give a try
   [JSPrintDemo](https://github.com/jayslu/JSPintDemo)

Comment: I spent a couple of hours trying to get UICollectionViewFlowLayout to cooperate with me, and finally I gave up and made my own UICollectionViewLayout, mostly using the tutorial here: http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial  ...However, I also needed variable-width cells and I was not sure how to accomplish this.  The code in your link helped me sort this out, specifically here: https://github.com/jayslu/JSPintDemo/blob/master/JSPintDemo/PintCollectionViewLayout.m